# Java: Removing component from JPanel

Tags: java, swing, components

I have a button that add an animated component to JPanel, but I do not declare a variable for them, just add a new component. Thats what the add button does:

```
public class addClickHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        panel.add(new Worm(15,400));    
    }

}
```

I have another button for removing them, but how do I remove just one of them per click? It doesn't matter which Worm I remove, I just want to remove one.
Thanks

Comment: How about `panel.remove()` ? If you do not care which one is removed, I guess `panel.remove(0)` should do the trick

Comment: You'd best remember to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after adding or removing any component.

Comment: Yeah, I did it. I was having a problem that when I repainted my panel, my buttons got behind it (the buttons were added in the frame), I had to set `panel.setOpaque(false)`.